# How to change the time on date time into 12 hour time?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M")
print timestr
```

When I run this code it comes out with 2015/10/27-20:36 but how would I make the time 8:36 instead

Comment: Did you read the documentation? There is another format specifier for 12-hour time.

Comment: what is it @nneonneo ?

Comment: Read the docs, they're there for these kind of questions

Answer (score 1):

timestr = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%I:%M")